# How find_each handles database updates while looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code that loops through an Active Record relation. Each loop makes an API call and depending on the result, it updates an "exported" flag in the database. The API endpoint it hits writes each request received from this process to its own database. It's writing duplicate records to its database which tells me my process is somehow making the API call multiple times for the same record.

Let's call the rails model Orders.

```
Orders.where(exported: false).find_each do |o|
  //call api
  //depending on result update "exported" column
  o.update(exported: true)
end
```

Could find_each somehow be getting the same record from the database more than once while trying to optimize batch sizes?

Comment: Possibly. By its nature, batch processing is subject to race conditions if other processes are modifying the database. But I cannot really say anything more than this, given the information above; a standalone `find_each { ... }`, will not yield the same record twice.

Comment: (But to be clear, this has nothing to do with "optimising batch sizes". This would only happen if - for example - a second process *edits some records* whilst this process is trying to loop through them.)

Comment: I do not believe a race condition exists. `Orders` is not modified by any other process while this export is happening.

Comment: Then in that case, no, `find_each` is not yielding the same record twice. *Look at the rails log*, and you should see a bunch of lines like: `Orders Load (24.8ms)  SELECT  "order".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."exported" IS false AND "orders"."id" > 12345 ORDER BY "orders"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000`. Your problem lies elsewhere. If you're still unconvinced, try logging each yielded record, and see where the "duplicate" happens.

Comment: Maybe -- just a shot in the dark -- you're running this as a job through `sidekiq`. The job failed, and went on the retry queue. Now, without realising it, you're running parallel duplicates of the same task.

Comment: Or maybe -- just another shot in the dark -- you have some unrelated service (e.g. a test suite) which is hitting the same external API; so you're mixing up the logs of more than one service.

Comment: I've been going through a process of elimination. I know nothing else is hitting the API. I'm not using sidekiq. I thought it could be the sql statement producing more than one result per record but I've proved that is not the case. I've ran the loop in rails console with a puts on the id and nothing seems out of the ordinary. Hence, my post as I'm running out of ideas. But thanks for the input. I'm using RestClient and I'll look at that more closely to see if a retry or something else is happening causing it to send the request more than once.